# WCF referenced from Windows Form Timing Out

Tags: c#, wcf

i have a windows form that references a WCF service. everything is working fine but sometimes i get an error stating that a time out has occured. i tried searching fora solution but the idea is not so clear so any help will be appreciated.

in the windows form the app.config file i added a binding this way:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="myBasicBinding" closeTimeout="00:51:00" openTimeout="00:51:00"
          receiveTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:51:00" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          transferMode="Streamed">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
      </basicHttpBinding>


<client>
 <endpoint address="wcf URL"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="myBasicBinding"
        contract="ServiceNew.IService1" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
    </client>
```

in the WCF web config should i add anything concerning the time out ?

also, i am sending a large amount of bytes so i am concerned with both the time out and the size of data sent. but note that the time out sometimes occurs after seconds of the call.

Comment: try increasing the receiveTimeout

Comment: its 30 minutes, and as i said the time out is happening after seconds sometimes.

Comment: Does the WCF service be connect to a database or performs some other action that could cause the timeout? Also, how many clients are hitting the service - is there high traffic volume?

Comment: @rashad.z Can you show me your timeout exception detail ? I wanna to help you.

Answer (score 0):

There could be many reasons for this. For example, it could be that your windows event log is full. I have experienced this in the context of security protocols and handshakes failing to complete. You should enable diagnostic tracing eg:

```
<system.diagnostics> 
<sources> 
    <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information,ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true"> 
        <listeners> 
            <add name="xml" /> 
        </listeners> 
    </source> 
    <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging"> 
        <listeners> 
            <add name="xml" /> 
        </listeners> 
    </source> 
</sources> 
<sharedListeners> 
    <add initializeData="C:\logs\TracingAndLogging-client.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" name="xml" /> 
</sharedListeners> 
<trace autoflush="true" />
```

Take a look at the following link for example http://www.andyfrench.info/2010/11/wcf-service-throwing-immediate-timeout.html